# Clearcase command to export an element

Tags: clearcase

Is there any command in clearcase which I can use to export a paricular version of a file? (i.e. an element). I am doing a find label with a given label (using `ct find . -ver lbtype(label) -cview -print` command) and want to export the elements returned by the find label to hard disk.

Comment: Did you manage to write the right script for calling `cleartool get` with the right parameters? If yes, a sanitized version of said script could be a valuable addition to this page, as a "complementary" answer.

Comment: I was using it from a perl script and did a simple `ct get -to $destfile $lblElt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[`cleartool get`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_get.htm)** could work (in a snapshot or dynamic view).

```
get –to C:\build\foo.c.temp \dev\hello_world\foo.c@@\main\2
```

You would need a script though, to extract from the `%CLEARCASE_PN%` the file name, and then pass to said script `%CLEARCASE_XPN%` (both variables are set by the cleartool find command)

That script would be called for each version found through an `-exec directive`

```
ct find . -ver lbtype(label) -cview -exec "myscript %CLEARCASE_PN% %CLEARCASE_XPN%"
```

That way, you could build an export path from the first argument, and use the second argument as the full extended pathname to use in order to "get" the version selected by the `find`.