# How to get a previous version in clearcase?

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I'm not a ClearCase expert... I would like to get a version of my project as it was, let's say one week ago, or maybe as it was when I finished an old activity.

Is it possible to do so? How should I do? (Please provide detailed steps :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For one file, you can use `cleartool get`, as described in "[Clearcase command to export an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042330/clearcase-command-to-export-an-element/6043443#6043443)".

But for a full view, I would recommend using a time-base config spec rule.
See for instance:

- "[how to find out all the activities happend in a branch in the last month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577980/how-to-find-out-all-the-activities-happend-in-a-branch-in-the-last-month/1578508#1578508)".
- "[ClearCase : Loading Older Version of a specific Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634509/clearcase-loading-older-version-of-a-specific-directory/635282#635282)"